# Html button text change

Tags: html, button, wait

I like to have this button. 
When you click on it the button text should change to "Updating...".
Then two seconds later it should change to "Updated!" and the button shouldn't be clickable after that.

Current Html Button script:

```
 <a class="btn-primary-md" id="buyButton" onclick="text = 'Updated!'">Update</a>
```

Comment: You mean this? https://fiddle.jshell.net/3ht2jzhm/ or with the 2 seconds timeout: https://fiddle.jshell.net/3ht2jzhm/1/

Comment: Yes. Just need two seconds later it changes again. Like "2 secs. since you clicked me!"

Comment: So this? https://fiddle.jshell.net/3ht2jzhm/2/

Comment: Yes! But you should only be able to click it one time.

Comment: I have all I need from here https://fiddle.jshell.net/3ht2jzhm/3/ Thx all that helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to sum up, you have a button/link and onclick you'll want:

1. The text of that element to change.
2. The element to be disabled.
3. After two seconds the value to change again to another
   value.

You can do this by extracting the JavaScript from the HTML for readability and maintainability like this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
 button.disabled = true;
  button.innerHTML = "Waiting...";
    
 setTimeout(function () {
   button.innerHTML = "Thank you!";
  button.disabled = false;
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: Thx. There is still that it should only work one time. (Be able to click one time)

Comment: @TobiasWangJørgensen see updated code which disables the button during the click and the value change.

Comment: Just changed true to false and false to true. Now it works!

Comment: Wish I could give a +Point

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Updated" id="buyButton" />
```

Javascript:

```
 function changeBtnTxt()
{
 document.getElementById("buyButton").value="Update"; 
  }
```

Maybe...

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onclick="changeBtnTxt()" type="button" value="Update" id="buyButton" />

function changeBtnTxt()
    {
    document.getElementById("buyButton").value="Updated";
   }
```

This is the correct one! Sorry!